# Environment.FailFast in c# application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, debugging, exception

I'd like to understand the `Environment.FailFast` rule in c# application. So , I made this code :

```
  public static void Main()
   {
       string strInput = GetString();
       Console.WriteLine(strInput);
       Console.ReadKey();
   }

   private static string GetString()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Get string");
       string s = Console.ReadLine();
       try
       {
           if (s == "Exit")
           {
                Environment.FailFast("Erreur fatale");
                return s;
           }
           else
           {
               return s;
           }
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           return "catch";
       }
       finally
       {
           s += "finally";
       }
   }
```

As I learned, the message are written to the `Windows application event log` and the application is terminated.

When I run the application and put `Exit` as a string :

1. The debbugger indicates an error :

[image]

1. I try to find the event log file, as indicated in [msdn](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308427/), but I don't find it
   [image]

I don't understand why the application didn't  shut down without throwing the exception? For the second point, How can I find the log file in my PC?

Comment: In Event Viewer, expand "Windows Logs" (or "Journaux Windows") on the left panel, and then click "Application".

Comment: @dcastro I get an empty list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Environment.FailFast(string)` exits the application immediately, without allowing any `catch` statements or finalizers to be run on the object.

You should only use this method if your application's state is at a point where it can **never** be recovered, and exiting the application is the only way to ensure something far worse than crashing does not happen. In your sample, using `Environment.Exit` with an exit code is more suitable, as it appears to be a graceful exit, rather than one forced through corrupt state.

In general, it is recommended to not use `FailFast` while the debugger is attached - this is [documented in the `System.Diagnostics.Assert` class](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Diagnostics/Assert@cs/1305376/Assert@cs):

```
// However, in CLR v4, Environment.FailFast when a debugger is attached gives you an MDA 
// saying you've hit a bug in the runtime or unsafe managed code, and this is most likely caused 
// by heap corruption or a stack imbalance from COM Interop or P/Invoke.  That extremely
// misleading error isn't right, and we can temporarily work around this by using Environment.Exit 
// if a debugger is attached.  The right fix is to plumb FailFast correctly through our native
// Watson code, adding in a TypeOfReportedError for fatal managed errors.  We may want a contract-
// specific code path as well, using COR_E_CODECONTRACTFAILED.
```

Which means the exception you're seeing in Visual Studio is down to a bug in the CLR, and could be safely ignored.

Their work around is as follows:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached) 
    Environment.Exit(COR_E_FAILFAST);
else
    Environment.FailFast(message);
```

Which means that while running with the debugger attached, you won't get the Event Log message written, while in release you do.

Answer (score 4):

I've reconstructed your problem with the following piece of code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
        Environment.FailFast("WOHO!");
    }
    finally { }
}
```

When running this **under the debugger**, I didn't see any exceptions registered either. Running this **without the debugger** (Ctrl + F5) makes the exception appear in the Event Viewer properly (see @aevitas answer or read [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/diagnostics/assert.cs,103) for why that happens):

[image: Event Viewer with the exception message]